# Coloring of JMenu / JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

I am trying to create a program with an overall theme of black backgrounds and neon(ish) blue foregrounds.  Everything for the most part is working as intended.

The components all have had their background,foreground, and border properties set.

The issue I am having is a random default style coloring on the JMenu when it is selected.  You can see the light grayish color around the JMenuItem elements.

Menu Issue

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNeGn.png]

Comment: The [look and feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) controls colors.

Comment: Maybe it can be controlled by the UIManager. Check out [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/).

Comment: I have set the look and feel, which allowed me to change a lot of what I was doing in the first place and replace the look and feel that Mac OS forces on Java.